# How to remove functions from object javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, lodash

In my app, I'm using **angular.js**.

I need to send (through PUT request) an object with 3 properties, like this:

```
var item = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

But when I do `console.log(item)`, it shows a lot of information I don't need, such as `$delete`, `$get`, and so on. Like this:

```
 {  
   ...
   $delete: function (params, success, error),
   $get: function (params, success, error),
   ...
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: 3
}
```

I think it's because is a javascript promise or something.
Is there any way to get only `a`, `b` and `c`? Maybe with lodash?

---

My Solution:

I used **lodash** like this:

```
 var valuesToPick = ['title', 'languageCode', 'jobTitle', 'location','economySegment', 'companyDescription' ...];

 var item = _.pick( vm.form, valuesToPick );
```

Comment: Looks like you are putting your data on a `$resource` or `$http` object, have you tried just putting your data on a new object like: `var item= {}; item.a = 1;` etc

Comment: I have a lot of properties, this is just an example, it has more, 20 I believe and I don't want to go like this 20 times :D.

Comment: I would add your solution as an actual answer then mark it correct for future SO users

Comment: I already did. Here you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [lodash](http://lodash.com) `_.pick` like this:

```
 var valuesToPick = ['title', 'languageCode', 'jobTitle', 'location','economySegment', 'companyDescription' ...];

 var item = _.pick( vm.form, valuesToPick );
```

Items is now free of functions, just your info.

Answer (score 3):

Plain Javascript

```
var objectFunctionLess=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectWithFunctions))
```

Answer (score 2):

They are inherit from `Object`, not owned by `item`.

If you want to iterate over own properties, use a `for`...`in` loop.

```
for (property in item) {
    item[property];
}
```

Comment: It loops for all the functions, properties, and all stuffs around the object. I finally went with **lodash** `_.pick`, but thanks anyway. I learnt something.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution but it should work:

Instead of:

```
submitFunction(object, function () {})
```

do the:

```
submitFunction(JSON.parse(angular.toJson(object)), function () {})
```

you can split it into:

```
var cleanObject = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(object))
submitFunction(cleanObject, function () {})
```